How to fetch data after Firebase authentication?
I have a mobile application, and I have implemented Firebase Authentication, but after User authenticates I want to send them to their home screen. Now, most of the user data is on a database (Cassandra), should I just pass the User's UID to the home screen page and have it connect via RESTFUL API to get User's data that match the User's UID? Shouldn't there be another authentication layer between? like when User's login via FireBase does it generate any session token or any handshake? because if anyone got that User's UID, they can be able to query any user's data?
I tried researching on this, but didn't get anything helpful.

You shouldn't do any of this inside your widget layer but in your data/business layer where you can keep login states and tokens independently of the UI.
